# How can an earlier block have a later timestamp?

Tags: blockchain, timestamp

Block #180966 has a timestamp of [2012-05-20 23:02:53](http://blockchain.info/block-height/180966).

Block #180967 has a timestamp of [2012-05-20 23:02:13](http://blockchain.info/block-height/180967).

How has the software permitted a later block to have an earlier timestamp than its predecessor?