# What is the standard deviation of block generation times?

Tags: blockchain, block-interval

A block is generated every 10 minutes, on average.
What is the standard deviation of this distribution?

It seems to be a measurable property, not a calculable one.

Is there a chart of the standard dev over time somewhere (should be added to blockchain.info)?

Comment: Why do you ask about s.e. only versus robust statistics like quantiles?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Excluding complications like difficulty changes and temporary blockchain splits, you can model the block generation time as an [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

An exponential distribution has a standard deviation equal to the expectancy value. This predicts a 10 minute standard deviation for Bitcoin.

---

Measuring the actual distribution isn't that easy. While each block contains a timestamp, that timestamp isn't very accurate, and sometimes the time difference between blocks is [even negative](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3743/how-can-an-earlier-block-have-a-later-timestamp).
The timestamp doesn't change over the course of a single share, and some miners deliberately use timestamps deviating from the actual time