# Block 620826 is 1 second before block 620825?

Tags: blockchain, block-header, timestamp

How does that happen?  Obviously the miner of 826 built his block on top of 825, but why is the time 1 second earlier?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't the timestamps in the block chain always increase?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/915/5406), [How can an earlier block have a later timestamp?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3743/5406)